# Whom to inform and how if my virusscanner screams with Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

When I tried to open a specific question earlier today my virus scanner screamed alarm in regards to a trojan (as I have Avast it is possible to be a false alert though). Whom / how shall I inform anyone about that? (aka that a question is possibly infected somehow?)

Opening that specific question itself is out of question as my virus scanner screamed as soon as I tried to open the page?

If needs be I can post even the URL to the question here (just refrained from doing so until I hear some word there as to what to do to avoid someone getting accidentally onto the question in case it was not a false alert by my virus scanner).

Edit: 
As the URL was asked for going to put up the URL and the infection info copied from my virus scanner alert message:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798745/how-can-i-remove-an-iframe-virus-from-all-of-php-files-on-my-website|{gzip} 
Infektion: PHP:Agent-QU [Trj]
```

Comment: On which question?

Comment: put it in the question was not sure if it is wise to post it or not (in case it was not a wrong alert...dont want anyone to risk infection who does not have appropriate anti virus protection).....maybe a bit too cautious on my side there but better save than sorry. Put it into a code segment so that no accidental clicks can happen

Comment: @Thomas it looks safe. It has the code of a virus posted as part of the question. There shouldn't be any risk of it being executed.

Comment: Ah ok then it was a wrong alert. I thought at first that it would be that until I saw "ok virus is about that trojan but the virus scanner screams about a different one...better save than sorry.".  But to come back to the original question then posting here on meta about such a situation is the way to go?

Comment: You flag the question as off topic, and hopefully soon the meta effect will sweep it under the rug.  Also, your antivirus sucks.  And you should be running as normal user.  VTC plox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798745/how-can-i-remove-an-iframe-virus-from-all-of-php-files-on-my-website